Pycharm documentation popup not working properly
Working in Pycharm with Tkinter, when I get to some (not all) function, the documentation and autocomplete suggestion are not showing up properly.
The following screenshot are from the same code, same computer, same everything.
Some function do show a popup with all the required info, and the autocomplete work fine. As shown with the tk.Button class.
When I get to the .place (or .pack), the pop up and auto complete are not showing anything.
Expected behavior
Current behavior
Code is running fine, the parameter do exist. Here is the code I am using:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk(className= " Extrusion Nesting")
root.geometry("900x500")


path_entry_var = tk.StringVar(root)
path_entry_box = tk.Entry(root, width= 75)
path_entry_box.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

browse_btn = tk.Button(root, width=10, text="Browse")
browse_btn.place(in_=path_entry_box, relx = 1 , rely=.5, anchor = 'w')

root.mainloop()

I ran trough the settings but could not find anything.
Reinstalled Python and Pycharm, still have the same issue.
Tried to compare with another computer (work computer) which doesn't have the same issue but couldn't find a mismatch in the setting.
Thanks in advance.
